# How to use regular expressions to add delimiters?

Tags: java, regex, netbeans

Hi I have a sample log file here:

```
Jan 1 22:54:17 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:22 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:23 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:41 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
```

The default delimiter is a semi-colon(;) and I want to separate the timestamp and "drop", as well as the "drop" with "%LOGSOURCE%" with that delimiter. I didnt get my expected result. This whole code is to insert the delimiter.) My main idea is to add the log file from a ArrayList into a String(which can use regular expressions according to my current knowledge of Java) and to add the delimiters accordingly.

The error is as shown below:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: 
    at testing.Testing.main(Testing.java:31) which starts from the line listString.replaceAll("regex command")

Note: I only tried it with putting the delimiter between the timestamp and "drop" and the error occured. I don't understand how to use regular expressions and I really need help on it!

```
public class Testing {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("filename")).useDelimiter(";");
    List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
    String listString = "";
    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
        // find next line
        String token1 = inFile1.next();
        temps.add(token1);
    }
    inFile1.close();
    for (String s : temps) {
        listString += s + "\t";
        listString.replaceAll(s,([a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\s)(drop)));
    }

    System.out.println(listString);

}
```

Comment: so you want to take `"Jan 1 22:54:41 drop   %LOGSOURCE%..."` and insert semi colons to get `"Jan 1 22:54:41;drop;%LOGSOURCE%"`? If not, please show before/after so we know what you want.

Comment: @Bohemian yes thats what i want

Comment: OK then, is "drop" a varying word, or is it always literally `drop`?

Comment: @Bohemian its always literally an entry in the log file itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
"[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\sdrop"
```

The above should work. You don't need all the parenthesis. The reason you get that particular exception is probably since the number of left and right parenthesis in your original expression don't match

Answer (score 0):

The [String.replaceAll(String regex,
                String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method accepts two `String` parameters.

You need to encapsulate the regex pattern in quotes. Also, in java you need to escape the `/` characters in the regex patters.

The line that uses the `replaceAll(...)` method should look something like this:

```
listString.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})(\\s)(drop)",s);
```

Comment: It still gives an error which is : 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 50
([a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\s)(drop))

Comment: @ih8coding Remove the last character of the regex pattern `)` but like @winterind said, you probably don't need all those groups, you can write the pattern without all the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Since all but the day of month in the line prefix is a fixed length, the simplest solution is:

```
line = line.replaceAll("^(... \\d+ .{8}) drop ", "$1;drop;");
```